# Is this `unsafe` code Undefined Behavior in Rust?

Tags: rust

I wanted to get a reference to structure from member references.
So, I wrote the following code.

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Data {
    x: i32,
    y: u32,
}

fn compose<'a>(x: &'a i32, y: &'a u32) -> Option<&'a Data> {
    use memoffset::offset_of;

    let x_address = x as *const i32 as usize;
    let y_address = y as *const u32 as usize;

    if x_address + offset_of!(Data, y) != y_address {
        return None;
    }

    return Some(unsafe { &*(x_address as *const Data) });
}
```

It seems to work correctly but I don't know if it is safe or not.
Is this undefined behavior or is there a good crate for solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is undefined behavior. It is not reported by Miri (although [a similar code is](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d3acc99140bdfa348e36e9f13727a83)) because it doesn't track ptr-to-int-to-ptr roundtrips, but it is still undefined behavior to access a reference past its bounds, not to mention that even if this was fine `compose()` would still be unsound because two references can happen to have adjacent addresses but come from different allocations.

It *may* not be undefined behavior if [UCG#134](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/134)/[UCG#256](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/256) will be decided to not be undefined behavior (you'll be allowed to read past the bounds of a reference). However, even in that case I'm not sure, because you have an active reference for `y` (although it is unlikely to matter). In the meantime, it is best to avoid this.